# Lumonosity stopped working after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04

After upgrade to 16.04 Luminosity stopped working and a streaming video from http://peregrinefund.org/webcam-peregrine will not display.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using grub as a bootloader? Upgrading might have overwritten some previous tweaks, allowing your brightness to be modified (if I understood your issue correctly)

Try the following:
Open up a new terminal, and type :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

(or use any other text editor than gedit if you want to), and replace the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT with this :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Save and close the file.
Finally, do :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and see if it helped

**[EDIT]**
You need adobe-flashplugin in order to see the video you mentioned correctly with Chromium.
Type in a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

And reboot your browser.
More info here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash and here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash if you're having trouble.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.  The live streaming video still does not display.  Couldn't load plug in in the screen area.  I'm using Chromium Web Brouser that was fine before upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: See my edit to try and solve your video feed problem.